# Regex to everything starting X until Y but not including another X

Tags: regex, notepad++

Trying to come up with notepad++ flavored regex to match `beginning` including `middle` but without another `beginning` in-between.

```
beginning //line 1

something something

middle //line 5 (first correct match lines 1 to 5)

beginning //line 7

something something

beginning //line 11

something something

middle //line 15 (second match lines 7 to 15 - incorrect because there is another 'beginning' in-between
```

My best current attempt is `beginning.*?(?!beginning)middle` (with multiline and . matching newlines) captures patterns as shown in comments.

Hot to fix it so that the second pattern only includes lines 11 to 15?

Comment: Use `beginning(?:(?!beginning).)*?middle`.

Comment: `^beginning\b.*(?:\R(?!\b(?:beginning|middle)\b).*)*\Rmiddle\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/msF2Sz/1

Comment: @41686d6564 and The fourth bird thank you for your help!